# Heroku API works fine with curl, but I'm having troubles with XMLHttpRequest. XHR, Heroku or me at fault?

Tags: javascript, heroku, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a Chrome extension that interacts with the [Heroku API](https://api-docs.heroku.com/), but it seems that requests made with `XMLHttpRequest` (XHR) are not handled the same way as `curl`. In particular, the Basic Auth doesn't seem to be used with XHR, but instead the cookies.

So if I run the following:

```
curl https://:yourapitokengoeshere@api.heroku.com/user -H "Accept: application/json"
```

I get the proper results without problems.

On the other hand, if I run the following in the Chrome JavaScript console for my extension page, the request's success will be based on if I'm logged in to Heroku or not.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.heroku.com/user", false, "", "yourapitokengoeshere")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
xhr.send()
```

If I'm logged in, I get the same result as `curl` in `xhr.responseText`. If I'm logged out, I get `GET https://:yourapitokengoeshere@api.heroku.com/user 401 (Unauthorized)`. I can see from the network tab that cookies are passed along and Heroku is basing its response on that rather than the API token passed as passed password in `XMLHttpRequest::open`. (I also tried to open `https://:yourapitokengoeshere@api.heroku.com/user` without using the username, password params with same results (as expected, but worth trying))

If you want to try that out, my `manifest.json` is simply:

```
{
  "name": "Testing Heroku.js",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "page": "test.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "https://api.heroku.com/"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And `test.html` is just an empty file so that I can open inspect the view and access a console in the extension's context. Create these two files anywhere and load the enclosing directory as an unpacked extension.

**So my question is**: is there anything I can do about it? Am I missing something? Is it something wrong with the Heroku API? Or `XMLHttpRequest`? I'm leaning towards the API misbehaving…

More generally, I'd be interested in understanding what makes a difference between the `XMLHttpRequest` call and the `curl` call.

From my research, I can't seem to use `XMLHttpRequest` without cookies and I can't change the user-agent to make it look like `curl`. I also tried a few things to make curl act like `XMLHttpRequest` (change user-agent, use the same headers), but `curl` always worked as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: The API docs page lets you test the API and it's actually possible to make `XMLHttpRequest` work by using the same method as they do: create a `POST` to "https://api-docs.heroku.com/request" with the real API method and data tucked into the POST data (`action=GET%20/apps`). Pretty pretty ugly but it does work. I'm guessing this would be unsupported and shut down if abused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a Heroku key as follows:

```
herokuKey = btoa(":" + herokuToken + "\n")
```

Then make your request with the appropriate headers.

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.heroku.com/apps")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3")
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", herokuKey)
xhr.send()
```

I pieced it together from this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-quickstart and used your example to adapt it to the web.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept your answer. I wanted to verify it myself first and I had my Heroku account info only on a computer I wasn't spending much time on. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Heroku's support team:

> this is Rails weirdness. The API, up until very recently, also handled the web UI etc, so its normal in that case to presume XHR is not an API request, but a request from an end-user on the API web site.
>
> Hopefully in the not too distant future our API won't be tied to this behavior anymore and will also be announced as a proper product (with proper documentation).

So, the problem is with the API.